# String manipulation with partial matching of elements

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a string list constructed as follows:

```
lis = {"Abcdef","Ghij Kl"," GHI 01", " ABC 02"}
```

and would like to rearrange this to give:

```
res = {"Abcdef","02","Ghij Kl","01"}
```

This involves replacing the all-caps portion of the last two elements with the matching string that begins with the same characters, then splitting the revised third and fourth element to give res.  [The white spaces in lis are intentional.]

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: It seems like there have been several of these kinds of questions from you lately. Maybe you should give it a go yourself this time. You might find useful functions here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringsAndCharacters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lis = {"Abcdef", "Ghij Kl", " GHI 01", " ABC 02"}

StringReplace[
 SortBy[lis, StringTake[StringTrim[#], 3] &]
 , " " ~~ (WordCharacter ..) ~~ " " ~~ k : (DigitCharacter ..) :> k]
```

> `{"Abcdef", "02", "Ghij Kl", "01"}`